# How to prevent Scrapy crawler from converting encoded characters?

Tags: scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy and running into an issue that I couldn't find an answer for.

One of the sites I'm trying to crawl uses an encoded character in the URL, specifically %2F. Scrapy is converting the %2F into "/" and the GET requests is returning a 404 error page.

Strangely, %3D is also in the URL, but Scrapy doesn't convert that to "=".

Here's a sample URL from the page's source code:

`/example/Product-SKU-512MCTR-T%2FA-Detail/444172?h=5&rr=0.14&hitprm=h%3D`

And here's what Scrapy tries to crawl:

`/example/Product-SKU-512MCTR-T/A-Detail/444172?h=5&rr=0.14&hitprm=h%3D`

Here's a snippet from the spider code:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "test"
    RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY = True
    allowed_domains = ["test.com"]
    start_urls = [  
    "http://www.test.com/jsp/results?h=#prows=100&sm=0"
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('example', )), callback="parse_auctions", follow= True),
    )
```

Comment: What makes you think *'Scrapy is converting the %2F into "/"'* ?

Comment: I haven't ran into this issue yet -- however, what happens if you double encode the URL?

Comment: My assumption is based on the "-T%2FA-" part of the scraped URL being converted into "-T/A-". I'm running the script in the DOS shell and the output as the script is running shows the T/A version of the URL.